# Illustrator - Always show paths, anchor points, etc

Tags: adobe-illustrator, path, anchor-point, windows-8

I want to draw along some lines in Illustrator. I realized that I can do that way more efficient if I can always see the paths, anchor point, etc. so is there a way to enable those permanently?

If that's not an option: Maybe someone with experience knows a better way to exactly draw along lines in illustrator.

Comment: Hi Jarvice, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your question. If you want to know more about the site, please see the [help] or ping one of us in the [chat] once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Comment: Hi Jarvice, this is the most relevant thread I could find. I am not sure if what you're asking is possible. [Making anchor points visible all the time](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/25886/making-anchor-points-visible-all-the-time). If you're trying to draw along lines, can you not just use path offset?